# How to get the data from gender dataset

Tags: machine-learning, python, random-forest

**May I know how to modify my Python programming thus it will be get the same result as refer to the image file?**

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

def load_pkl(gender_36):
    with open('gender_36.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    return df

feat_labels = load_pkl.columns[1:]
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, random_state=2, n_jobs=-1)
forest.fit(X_train, y_train)
importances = forest.feature_importances_
indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]

for f in range(X_train.shape[1]):
    print("%2d) %-*s %f" % (f + 1, 30, feat_labels[indices[f]], importances[indices[f]])) 

plt.title('Feature Importances')
plt.bar(range(X_train.shape[1]), importances[indices], color='lightblue', align='center')
plt.xticks(range(X_train.shape[1]), feat_labels[indices], rotation=90)
plt.xlim([-1, X_train.shape[1]])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**Please see the image file -**

[image]
**The error message is -**

```
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 6.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
C:\Users\HSIPL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\parentpoller.py:116: UserWarning: Parent poll failed.  If the frontend dies,
                the kernel may be left running.  Please let us know
                about your system (bitness, Python, etc.) at
                ipython-dev@scipy.org
  ipython-dev@scipy.org""")

runfile('C:/Users/HSIPL/Desktop/New f/a i/Homework 9 draft.py', wdir='C:/Users/HSIPL/Desktop/New f/a i')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\HSIPL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2961, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-1-e53e7077ed93>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/HSIPL/Desktop/New f/a i/Homework 9 draft.py', wdir='C:/Users/HSIPL/Desktop/New f/a i')

  File "C:\Users\HSIPL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\HSIPL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/HSIPL/Desktop/New f/a i/Homework 9 draft.py", line 12
    return df
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

**Please help me on this case**

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a “return df” as the last line in your “load_pkl” function. That way when you call the load_pkl() it returns the data frame. It should work after that.

Comment: The new error message is - IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: @vokoyo you changed how you wrote the function. But if you use that method you have to first add the implementation for the with block then make sure the return fg is on the same alignment as the with line

Comment: I cannot understand your reply - could you please write the sample code as a reference because of it is good for understanding

Comment: Indent error means that you have a code sequence for which something like „tab“ is expected. Eg. the „tab“ after opening a loop. Check your code. This is about bad code, not about data science.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html